# R shiny how to updateDateRange with dynamic UI

Tags: r, shiny

I have uiOutput that will add more dateRangeInput when I change the baseline seasons. Now, I want to click the action button to update the season 1 for example from "2016-05-01" to "2019-05-02". I tried below attempt but it's not doing what I want, help please.

[image: pic1]

```
library(shiny)
library(purrr)

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput(
    "select_season", label = "Baseline Seasons",
    choices = c("1","2","3","4"), selected = "1"
  ),
  uiOutput("multi_seasons"),
  actionButton("update", "Update")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  season_names <- reactive(paste0("Season ", seq_len(input$select_season)))
  output$multi_seasons <- renderUI({
    map(season_names(), ~ dateRangeInput(.x, label = .x,
                                         start = isolate(input[[.x]][1]),
                                         end = isolate(input[[.x]][2])))
  })
  
  # action button to update dateRange
  observeEvent(input$update, {
    updateDateRangeInput(
      session, inputId = season_names(),
      start = "2016-05-01",
      end = "2019-05-02"
    )
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have spaces in the `inputId`. Change the id reactive to something like

```
season_names <- reactive(paste0("Season", seq_len(input$select_season)))
```

or

```
season_names <- reactive(paste0("Season_", seq_len(input$select_season)))
```

Also, you will have issues for any season beyond one. You'll need to select a single value. Something maybe like

```
updateDateRangeInput(
      session, inputId = tail(season_names(), 1),
      start = "2016-05-01",
      end = "2019-05-02"
    )
```

Comment: Thanks! So the season_names are indeed the inputID, I was testing it in my full app when I tried to get rid of the space but didn't work so I didn't try again in this basic example, really appreciate your help!